# How to get the necessary local yaw angles to produce a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

This is a geometry question

Say I want to generate the points `(x,y)` for a circle as you see in the figure

[image: circle and yaws]

However the only way I can describe these points is through local yaw angles.(the green arrows)

The equations to generate `(x,y)` from yaw angles are:

[image: equations]

$\Delta_t$ is a constant, and the only thing I can give is φ The rest are calculated.(of course the first point is known - the origin)

So my question is, what are the values of the local yaw φ angles in order to construct a circle?

EDIT： Made a mistake using phi small and capital in the equation. I will rewrite it with the first one being theta

The equation is more understandable as

$\theta_{n+1}=\sum\phi_t\Delta t_n$

and the only thing I can specify is $\phi_t$

Comment: If both $v_n$ and $\phi_n$ are constant (i.e., do not depend on $n$), and $\Delta t$ is small you will get a reasonable approximation of a circle. Ratio $v_n/\phi_n$ will define the circle's radius.

Comment: so the radius is   `vn/ϕn` ?

Comment: Not sure what is $\theta$, but yes, $v/\phi$ will approximate the radius. The smaller is your $\Delta t$ the closer $v/\phi$ will be to the radius.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake writing the greek letters. The one that I can specify is the small phi , because the capital phi is calculated. In your comment $\phi$ is φ？

Comment: @blamocur I clarified the equation. Could you take a look?

Comment: I am confused: if $\Delta t$ is constant then why you use $\Delta t_n$ in other places? Is $v_n$ constant?  Also: do you need to have a circle with specific radius, or any radius will do?

Comment: Also: is $v_n$ constant or depends on $n$?

Comment: In general (meaning in the original data I have) they are dependent, but I am simplifying the problem. So I am setting  $\Delta t$ as constant and v (velocity) too.  About the radius, it would be neat if I can find the angles for a specific radius. (So that I can make circles of the radius I choose). Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the required radius, and let's assume that the motion is around the origin
(0,0) and that it starts from point $(0,R)$.

At time $n$ we are at point $x_n, y_n$, and (if we our algorithm is correct) we have
$x_n^2 + y_n^2 = R^2$.

Our goal is to find $\phi_n$ such that $x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}$
stays on the circle, i.e., $x_{n+1}^2 + y_{n+1}^2 = R^2$. By plugging this into the
formula from the original post we get
$$
\left(v_n^2 \Delta t_n^2 \cos^2\phi_n
+ 2v_n \Delta t_n \cos \phi_n x_n + x_n^2
\right)
+
$$
$$
+\left(v_n^2 \Delta t_n^2 \sin^2\phi_n
+ 2v_n \Delta t_n \sin \phi_n y_n + y_n^2
\right) = R^2
\;\;\;\Longrightarrow$$
$$
v_n^2 \Delta t_n^2 +
2v_n\Delta t_n \left(x_n\cos\phi_n + y_n\sin\phi_n  \right) = 0
\;\;\;\Longrightarrow$$
$$
x_n\cos\phi_n + y_n\sin\phi_n = -\frac{v_n\Delta t_n}{2}
$$
Since $x_n = R\cos\theta_n$ and $y_n = R\sin\theta_n$
we get
$$
x_n\cos\phi_n + y_n\sin\phi_n =
R \cos\left(\theta_n-\phi_n \right)
\;\;\;\Longrightarrow
$$
$$
\cos\left(\theta_n - \phi_n \right)
 = -\frac{v_n\Delta t_n}{2R}
\;\;\;\Longrightarrow
$$$$
\phi_n = \theta_n - \arccos\frac{v_n\Delta t_n}{2R}
$$